# Attempt to read from column ordinal '0' is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

Im having a problem with my first column ForumGroup in my stored procedure in my Entities collection. I get this error.

Attempt to read from column ordinal '0' is not valid.  With CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, you may only read from column ordinal '3' or greater.

My Sql:

```
    DECLARE @Forums TABLE(ForumGroup nvarchar(100), Title varchar(100), Description varchar(100), ThreadCount int, LastPostBy nvarchar(50),
LastPostDate datetime, LastPostTitle varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Forums(ForumGroup, Title, Description, ThreadCount, LastPostBy, LastPostDate, LastPostTitle)
SELECT
(
    CASE WHEN F.ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums S WHERE S.ForumID = F.ParentID)           
    ELSE
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums S WHERE S.ParentID IS NULL)
    END) AS ForumGroup,
Title, Description, 
ThreadCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts P WHERE  P.ForumID = F.ForumID),
LastPostBy = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedBy FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
LastPostDate = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedDate FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),
LastPostTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC) 

FROM Forums F WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY ForumGroup

SELECT * FROM @Forums
```

my C#:

```
public class Forums
{        
    public List<Forum> GetForums()
    {

        using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=CMSEntities"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "CMSEntities.sproc_Forums_GetForums";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                List<Forum> forums = new List<Forum>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Forum forum = new Forum(
                        1,
                        "",
                        DateTime.Now,
                        reader["Title"].ToString(),
                        reader["Description"].ToString(),
                        0,
                        false,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        true,
                        reader["ForumGroup"].ToString(),
                        (int)reader["ThreadCount"],
                        null,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        null);
                    forums.Add(forum);
                }
                return forums;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you have the following in a Watch window and debug step-through. It will error in Debug but not in Release mode.
"reader[0]" in Watch and Code will cause this error.
Remove any 'cursor' reads that will progress the cursor.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this [blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/11/15/commandbehavior-sequentialaccess.aspx).

Quote to blog post:

> If you open a reader with SequentialAccess you must read the columns
>   sequentially, you can't read column 1 and then read column 0. You have
>   to do it the other way around.

Comment: Ok then what do put instead so i don't get that error. I just want to read all columns how do i do that

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of [CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx):

> "When you specify SequentialAccess, you are required to read from the
>   columns in the order they are returned, although you are not required
>   to read each column. Once you have read past a location in the
>   returned stream of data, data at or before that location can no longer
>   be read from the DataReader."

Once you have read past `Title` and `Description`, you can't read `ForumGroup`, you can only read from the fourth (index 3) column and beyond.

So, you basically have three options:

- Use a different command behaviour.
- Specify the order that you return the fields from the stored procedure so that they match the code. (You should specify the fields and not use `select *` anyway.)
- Read the values into variables first, so that you can read them in the order that they are returned, then use the variables to create the `Forum` objecct.

Comment: Ok then what do put instead so i don't get that error. I just want to read all columns how do i do that when i just use ExecuteReader it says The CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess property must be specified for this command object.

Comment: I keep getting this error when i changed the CommandBehavior. The CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess property must be specified for this command object. I changed the order of the select statement as it appears in my complex type

Comment: @KDM: Then you have a data type that requires that command behaviour. You have to use some of the other two options.

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote? If you don't say what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below mentioned code.

EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "CMSEntities.sproc_Forums_GetForums";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default))
            {
                List<Forum> forums = new List<Forum>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Forum forum = new Forum(
                        1,
                        "",
                        DateTime.Now,
                        reader["Title"].ToString(),
                        reader["Description"].ToString(),
                        0,
                        false,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        true,
                        reader["ForumGroup"].ToString(),
                        (int)reader["ThreadCount"],
                        null,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        null);
                    forums.Add(forum);
                }
                return forums;
            }
        }
    }
}

Hope it helps.
```